# how to decode base64 encoded data into ascii in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

im getting json object from the api , in that object one field is encoded with base 64 format. after getting the response i need to decode the base64 data and need to show in the plain text.
sample data

```
{"id":33132,"dataFormat":"TEVOOjA="}//base64 to ascii i.e LEN:0
```

desired output - LEN:0

```
 <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
                $http.get('url', {
                    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic a2Vybyt==' }
                })
                    .then(function (response) {
                   $scope.names = response.data;
                   $scope.EncodedData = names.dataFrame;
                   $scope.decodedFrame = atob(EncodedData);
                });
            });
    </script>
<h2>{{names.decodedFrame }}</h2>
```

Comment: See [MDN Web API Reference -- window.atob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var string = 'Hello World!';
```

// Encode the String

```
var encodedString = btoa(string);
console.log(encodedString); // Outputs: "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh"
```

// Decode the String

```
var decodedString = atob(encodedString);
console.log(decodedString); // Outputs: "Hello World!"
```

**in Angular :**

**HTML :**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
  <div>encoded jsonData.dataFormat : {{ jsonData.dataFormat }}</div>
  <div>decoded jsonData.dataFormat : {{ decodedFrame }}</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
function LoginController($scope) {
  $scope.jsonData = {
    "id": 33132,
    "dataFormat": "TEVOOjA="
  };
  $scope.decodedFrame = atob($scope.jsonData.dataFormat)
}
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/2pwauuLu/

Comment: i dnt have original text, i have to decode only encoded text

Comment: @Swapna: Use only Decode portion of above suggested code. encodedString = "TEVOOjA="; var decodedString = atob(encodedString);
console.log(decodedString);

Comment: thanks. how to send single value   $scope.decodedFrame = atob(names.dataFrame);im using json object. in that one field is dataFrame that i need to decode

Comment: thanks a lot @nikhil

Comment: @Swapna : Your Welcome !

Answer (score 0):

Try using a base64 encoder/decoder like [this](https://github.com/ninjatronic/angular-base64) one.

Answer (score 0):

```js
s = atob("TEVOOjA=");
console.log(s); //LEN:0
```

See [MDN Web API Reference -- window.atob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob)